# Stop webview reload/refresh when app comes to Foreground

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I m working on a multiview UIWebView. This webview loaded an external url. This url get reloaded everytime the app comes to the foreground and goes to the first page. This is causing the user to enter any kind of data again and again. Is there a way to stop this url from reloading from webview?

I have already tried using:
1. [self.webView stopLoading];
2. shouldStartLoadingWithRequest making it return NO;
3. UIWebViewNaviagationTypeReload and UIWebViewNaviagationTypeOther
to check if the webviews load status.
But no luck. The Webview keeps reloading?
Can anyone tell me is there any other way to stop the refresh for this url inside webview?

Comment: Where have you put the web view loading call ? And do you have some code in AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive ?

Comment: The webview is called when the webview has to be filled with some content. applicationDidBecomeActive method is not having any code.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem. Did you find any solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58274674/web-app-auto-redirecting-to-the-initial-page-on-ios-problem-it-should-not-redir